# C++ : about memory management

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm a bit new to C++ and been doing programming in Obj-C and Java up until now.

Say, I have a class:

```
class Person {

private:
   Wife *current_wife;
   //.....
};
```

So obv I need to implement a setter method to change the Wife instance variable.

Like this:

```
Person::SetCurrentWife (Wife *new_wife) {

    current_wife = new_wife;
}
```

That would be a shalllow copy.

So somewhere from the main loop or something I call:

```
Person *some_person = new Person();
...
Wife *wife = new Wife ();
some_person->SetCurrentWife(wife);
```

So I'm confused: will there be a memory leak here? Should I delete the wife object here or in Person's destructor? In Obj-C I would release the current wife and then send a retain message to wife object above, but what is the proper way of doing setter methods in C++?

Comment: Since you're new to C++, heed this advice: never use `new`, `delete`, or pointers. As an exception, you *may* use `new` inside the constructor of a smart pointer, but only after you have determined that you really do require dynamic storage.

Comment: Kerrek forgot to recommend [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642) :)

Comment: In OO you don't obv need a setter, you need functions to let the object do something (divorce, remarry).  Setters may be convenient, they're not obv.

Comment: The questions you have to ask yourself are: "Does a `Person` own his `Wife`?" and "When a `Person`'s lifetime ends, should his `Wife` be automatically destroyed?".

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Good advice! Here are a reference to why if anyone would be interested in why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/in-c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible

Comment: @Charles: obviously software objects shouldn't be confused with real-life objects ;)

Comment: @stefaanv Software objects (in the OO sense, not in the C++ standard sense) often model real-life objects, or some aspects of real-life objects.  I can't imagine a program where an object representing my `Wife` would be destroyed because I die.

Comment: The problem with any answer that kneejerk-cries for "smart pointers" is that they're missing the point - the *first* question in the design process shouldn't be how to implement dynamic storage, but *whether you need dynamic storage at all*. This is one of the biggest crimes I hold Java and any of this "modern OO" responsible for: It has completely eroded people's ability to think about the underlying *logical structure* of their data. *First* you think about lifetime, and only then do you proceed to implement the required semantics.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That is 1 of the issues with OO: people try to model real-life too much, especially when teaching OO. You need to model based on your problem domain to work towards a solution.  The joke of course being "When a Person's lifetime ends, should his Wife be automatically destroyed?"

Comment: @stefaanv You don't want to model real-life too exactly, but a number of classes in a typical application will model specific aspects of real-life.  At least if the application is to have any applicability in real-life.  (But this is all beside the point.  The idea is just to use it as a lever for further discussion of possible solutions.  There is no one absolute solution for all cases; the OP has to consider the larger design.  And IMHO, the issue of lifetime has to be considered.  Regardless of the language, smart pointers, garbage collection or whatever.)

Comment: That was merely an example . And yes, I do need to use dynamic memory.  Thanks for the helpful answers (both these and below), folks.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you're trying to do.  First, as Kerrek SB has
commented, you don't want to use pointers if value semantics can be
applied: if `Wife` is copyable and assignable, there's almost no reason
to allocate it dynamically.  In this case, however, I'm guessing that
`Wife` derives from `Person` (although perhaps a decorator for `Person`
would be more appropriate, since the fact that a given `Person` isA 
`Wife` can change over time), that there might even be types derived
from `Wife` (and that `Person::current_wife` might want to hold one of
these), and that in fact, `Wife` has identity; you don't want copies of
the same wife all over the place.

If this is the case, then you really have to define a protocol for the
interactions of other classes with `Wife`.  Typically, the lifetime of
`Wife` will not depend on the `Person` who holds it (although if it is a
decorator, it might), so `Person` should just hold a pointer to it, as
you've done.  Most likely, the `Wife` object will have various functions
which—implicitly or explicitly—control its lifetime: you
might have something like:

```
void Wife::die()
{
    //  ...
    delete this;
}
```

for example.  In that case, however, whoever is married to `Wife` will
have to be informed, so that `current_wife` doesn't point to a dead
spouse.  Typically some variant of the observer pattern can be used for
this.  (Note that you have exactly the same issue in Java; you don't
want `Person::current_wife` to point to a dead `Wife`.  So you'd still
need a `Wife::die()` function, and the observer pattern to notify the
spouse.)

In cases like this (which in my experience represent the vast majority
of dynamically allocated objects in C++), about the only difference
between C++ and Java is that C++ has a special syntax for calling the
“destructor”; in Java, you use the usual function call
syntax, and you can give the function any name you wish (although
`dispose` seems widely used).  The special syntax allows the compiler to
generate additional code to release the memory, but all of the other
activities associated with the end of the object lifetime still have to
be programmed (in the destructor, in C++—although in this case, it
might make sense to put some of them directly in the `Wife::die`
function).

Answer (score 4):

You should use a smart pointer.

If you use regular pointer, practice caution!

You should `delete` the old `current_wife` member both on the destructor and on the set method. Setting a new wife will lead to the memory leak of the old one, as the pointer to that allocated memory is lost (unless you manage the memory outside the class - see below).

But even doing so, you need to make sure that no-one outside the class can delete the member. You have to decide whether memory management is left to the class or dispached to the outside of the class, and stick to it.

Comment: -1 Because it's simply bad advice.  I'd be very surprised if smart pointers implement the desired lifetime semantics---you really don't believe that it is impossible for my wife to die before I do (or that my death should trigger hers), do you?

Comment: @JamesKanze so why would that be a problem? Would using smart pointers restrict you from deleting the wife object beforehand, or deleting it after person has died?

Comment: it depends on the smart pointer, but if you delete something managed by any of the standard smart pointers, you're in undefined behavior land.  If you use `shared_ptr`, especially, the lifetime of the object is out of your hands.

Comment: @James: This is probably culture-specific. It is in general bizarre to have a Person class and then a Wife class. In some cultures Persons marry other Persons.

Comment: @UncleBens The whole structure is a bit dubious: if `Wife` derives from `Person`, then some people are wives from the day they're born to the day they die.  And if `Wife` doesn't derive from `Person`, one wonders about a society where wives aren't people.  (I think I vaguely mentioned possibly using the decorator pattern, where `Wife` is a decorated `Person`.)

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointers can help you

```
using boost::shared_ptr; // or std::shared_ptr, or std::tr1::shared_ptr or something like this
class Person { 

private: 
   shared_ptr<Wife> current_wife; 
   //..... 
}; 

Person::SetCurrentWife (shared_ptr<Wife> new_wife) { 

    current_wife = new_wife; 
}
```

And now you should not delete any wife at all.

```
shared_ptr<Person> some_person ( new Person );
...  
shared_ptr<Wife> wife ( new Wife );  
some_person->SetCurrentWife(wife);
```

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for disaster.  There are only a very few cases where `shared_ptr` works, and I suspect that this is not one of them.  For two reasons: first, it's probable that `Wife` also knows who she's a wife of, so you have a cycle (and you need a cycle, since if something happens to `Wife`, the current spouse must be informed).  And second, the lifetime of `Wife` is certainly not dependent on the lifetime of the spouse---if `Wife` dies, she shouldn't be kept alive just because the spouse happens to maintain a pointer to her.

Comment: @JamesKanze that's why there is `boost::weak_ptr` I'd guess. It allows breaking cycles and safe notification of dead objects.

Comment: @ChristophHeindl So which pointers should be weak, and which ones not?  `boost::weak_ptr` is a hack, and not generally usable.

Comment: @JamesKanze that depends on what your application tries to accomplish. One way: maintain `weak_ptr` for inter-person relationships and separately hold a container of `shared_ptr` of all living persons. After all you can always upgrade a `weak_ptr` to `shared_ptr` temporarily if you need to ensure 'alivness' while operating on inter-person relationships.

Comment: @ChristophHeindl That would, of course, work.  Sort of, anyway; the spouse would probably like to know immediately when `Wife` died, for example.  And the extra vector seems like added complexity for no real reason.  It seems like the design has been twisted just so that you can say you are using a smart pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze what's your suggesstion?

Comment: @ChristophHeindl I discussed several in my own answer.